# Set a cron job to update article information depending on its vote values

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to set a cron job that will execute every 15 minutes. Before going into deep description of these query I'll explain how my database works.

I have 2 tables '**stories**' and '**votes**'. All information about article like title, category etc. is stored in the '**stories**' table. It's not a big surprise that all the votes related to article are stored in a '**votes**' table. In the votes table there is a field named '**item_name**' which corespondents to the '**id**' of article that is in 'stories' table. Finally, in '**stories**' table I have a field named '**showing**' which is by default set to 0. And I want to change it to different values depending on how many votes article has, but more about it latter.

Here is a structure of my database:

**Stories table**

[image]

---

**Votes table**

[image]

---

Ok now when I cleared database structure lets get down to my question. I need a query that would look at all articles where showing=0 and sum up votes that corespondent to a particular article. If sum of votes = 10 than set showing=1 if sum of votes = -10 than set showing=2. I don't know how such query would look, I really don't :/
So could anyone suggest a solution please?

**Addition:** I asked similar question before and some people suggested trigger's or updating database each time a vote is cast. But I would rather check it every 15 min with cron job. )))

**EDIT:** Just to give you more understanding of how it works )))

For example this row from 'stories' table:

**id|** 12 
**st_auth |** author name 
**st_date |** story date 
**st_title|** story title 
**st_category|** story category 
**st_body|** story body 
**showing|** 0 for pending, 1 for approved and 2 for unapproved

Co responds to this one from ;votes' table:

**id|** 83 
**item_name|** 12 (id of article) 
**vote_value|** 1 for upvote -1 for downvote 
etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(vt.vote_value), vt.item_name
from Votes vt
join stories st on st.id = vt.item_name
and st.showing = 0
group by vt.item_name
```

This should give you all the articles with showing 0 and total vote value. After that you can process them row by row  and update voting if needed.

Added:
I am not a PHP programmer, I mostly do PERL, but I guess it has to be something like this:

```
<?php 
    $query = "select sum(vt.vote_value) as vote_value, vt.item_name from Votes vt join stories st on st.id = vt.item_name and st.showing = 0 group by vt.item_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row['vote_value'] > 9) {
            $showing = 1;
        }
        else if($row['vote_value'] < -9) {
            $showing = 2;
        }
        else {
            $showing = 0;
        }
        $query2 = "UPDATE `stories` SET `showing` = $showing WHERE `id` = '".$row['item_name']."'";
        mysql_query($query2); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: This selects all stories with showing = 0 and sums their votes great, But how would I use it to set showing =1 and 2 on articles with certain vote sums? #Koddlee Yin uses $ourCount = $ourCount + $row['vote_value']; and if else conditions to set showings, but how would I do the same with your query? Sorry, I'm just not good with php yet.

Comment: one thing, in second query SET `showing` = 0 do you mean SET showing = $showing ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure If I fully understand your question, but What I'm getting is this:

```
<?php
    //this is placed after connecting to and selecting your mysql database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `stories` WHERE `showing` = 0";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //count how many votes we have
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `votes` WHERE `item_name` = '".$row['id']."'"; //assuming item_name in votes = id in stories
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
        $ourCount = 0;
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
            $ourCount = $ourCount + $row['vote_value'];//assuming vote value is where your +1 or -1 or whatever value is stored.
        }

        if($ourCount >= 10)
        {
            //I'm assuming, you want to show it if the votes equal or are greater than 10...
            $query3 = "UPDATE `stories` SET `showing` = 1 WHERE `id` = '".$row['id']."'";
            mysql_query($query);
        } else if($ourCount <= -10) {
            //again i'm assuming you want to set 2 where votes is equal to or less than -10
            $query3 = "UPDATE `stories` SET `showing` = 2 WHERE `id` = '".$row['id']."'";
            mysql_query($query);
        } else {
            //you can really take this part out as it's redundant, but i'm placing it here anyways.
            $query3 = "UPDATE `stories` SET `showing` = 0 WHERE `id` = '".$row['id']."'";
            mysql_query($query);
        }
    }
?>
```

What this does is gets all rows from "stories" where "showing" = 0. Then it searches votes for any item_name with the value of the story id. From there, it adds the "item_value" which can be negative for down votes. It then figures out if the end result is greater than equal to 10, less than equal to -10, or (-10,10). It then executes the corresponding query to set the showing to 1, 2, and 0 respectively.

Hope I understood your question properly!

Comment: Yes, you understood me perfectly right, I'll test this now and let you know if it works, thank you.

Comment: But, the line $ourCount = $ourCount + $row['vote_value']; Does it sum up all votes associated with article?

Comment: Yes as it's inside the while loop which is going through every vote for that item name

Comment: This solution is not great because you are doing a select for each story. It will work very slow when the number of the articles become large.

Comment: Not great, I'm aware, but optimization was not the question, so I just built a simple solution. @Andrey But don't you have to select every single story with the showing = 0 as you need to pull the id from each of the stories?

Comment: Optimization is ALWAYS the question and is implied. Stuff has to be written once and properly. Instead of written somehow and then rewritten when it stop working well. See my answer on select.