# Script for cron job not working. PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron

I set up a cron job to run the following script every 30 min, Basically this script selects article info from **stories** table where field **showing=0** And it than counts votes related to that article, the votes are located in **votes** table. **itemname_field** in votes table is equal to **id** field in stories table.
If you need more information on database structure and voting system, I describe it in depth here: 
[Set a cron job to update article information depending on its vote values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609678/set-a-cron-job-to-update-article-information-depending-on-its-vote-values)

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die (mysql_error("There was an error in connection"));
    mysql_select_db("database") or die (mysql_error("There was an error in connection"));

    $query = "select sum(vt.vote_value) as vote_value, vt.item_name from Votes vt join stories st on st.id = vt.item_name and st.showing = 0 group by vt.item_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($row['vote_value'] > 9) {
            $showing = 1;
        }
        else if($row['vote_value'] < -9) {
            $showing = 2;
        }
        else {
            $showing = 0;
        }
        $query2 = "UPDATE `stories` SET `showing` = $showing WHERE `id` = '".$row['item_name']."'";
        mysql_query($query2); 
    }
?>
```

---

Can anyone suggest the reason, why this script is not working? If everything is alright with script, could it be something in cron job that needs to be done?

**EDIT:** when I run script in browser it gives the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL
```

Which is this line `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: In what way is it *not working*?

Comment: It's not doing the job, I've set several articles to showing=0 and added vote values to them that are grater or smaller than (9, -9).
But after cron job runs nothing changes.

Comment: Check your syslog to make sure the script is actually ran. Also check your php error log.

Comment: I checked syslog, script was ran several times, I accessed script through browser and it echoed an error, I made an edit showing it in my question.

Comment: That means your query is invalid. Run it though a mysql client to get more information, or echo `mysql_error()` in php.

Comment: You have error handling everywhere except when you actually run the query. Check the result of `mysql_query()` and append error handling there as well. And as a side note: if you don't intend to numerically access the query results, use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead.

Comment: I didn't know mysql_error() function before, Thank you this fixed the problem ))) it was a capital letter "V" in votes table. Do you want to provide a sort of an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can answer the question yourself. This is possible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you quote means you have an error in your query. Run it though a mysql client to get more info, or echo `mysql_error()` in php.

In such cases `mysql_query()` returns boolean false, you can use this for error handling.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in this part:

```
$query = "... from Votes vt join ...";
```

it should not be capital "V".